# Derived version of equivalence between motives and representations of Motivic galois groups?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, motives, tannakian-category

A slight variant $\tilde Mot_{num}(k,\mathbb{Q})$ of the category of pure motives $Mot_{num}(k,\mathbb{Q})$ is a Tannakian category equivalent to a category of representations of some algebraic group $GMot_k$ (the Motivic galois group):

$$
Mot_{num}(k,\mathbb{Q}) \simeq Rep(GMot_k)
\,.
$$

[nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivic+Galois+group)

> What it is known about the Derived category version (The derived category of motives) of this equivalence?

**Equivalence between the sub-category of compact objects of (say for example) étale Motivic sheaves and the derived category of representations of finite dimension of (Ayoub) Motivic galois groups**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and $\operatorname{DM}_{gm}(k)_{\mathbb Q}$ the ∞-category of rational geometric motives over $k$. A mixed Weil cohomology theory induces a symmetric monoidal exact functor

$$
R: \operatorname{DM}_{gm}(k)_{\mathbb Q} \to D_c(\mathbb Q),
$$

where $D_c(\mathbb Q)$ are the compact=dualizable objects in the derived ∞-category of $\mathbb Q$.
For abstract reasons, there exists a best possible commutative Hopf algebra $H$ in $D(\mathbb Q)$ such that, if $G=\operatorname{Spec}(H)$, then $R$ lifts to

$$
\tilde R: \operatorname{DM}_{gm}(k)_{\mathbb Q} \to \operatorname{Rep}_{D_c(\mathbb Q)}(G).
$$

This general construction can be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.1761v3.pdf) by Iwanari.
As you know, Ayoub has also [constructed](http://user.math.uzh.ch/ayoub/PDF-Files/GaloisMotivic-1.pdf) $H$, but only in the homotopy category of $D(\mathbb Q)$, which is not enough to define $\tilde R$.

Let me now assume that $k\subset \mathbb C$ and  that $R$ is the Betti realization. Ayoub then proves that $H$ is connective, so that $\tau_{\leq 0}H$ is a Hopf algebra in rational vector spaces. If $G^{cl}=\operatorname{Spec}(\tau_{\leq 0}H)$, we then have a closed immersion $i\colon G^{cl}\hookrightarrow G$, whence

$$
i^*\circ \tilde R: \operatorname{DM}_{gm}(k)_{\mathbb Q} \to \operatorname{Rep}_{D_c(\mathbb Q)}(G^{cl}).
$$

Choudhury and Gallauer Alves de Souza [proved](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.6104v2.pdf) that the group scheme $G^{cl}$ is isomorphic to Nori's motivic Galois group.

The strongest conjecture one can make here is that $i^*\circ\tilde R$ is an equivalence of ∞-categories. This conjecture is equivalent to the conjunction of two conjectures: $\tilde R$ is an equivalence, and $G^{cl}=G$. It also clearly implies the conservativity conjecture (that $R$ is conservative) and the existence of the motivic $t$-structure. Conversely, the existence of a $t$-structure such that $R$ is $t$-exact implies that $G^{cl}=G$. The conservativity of $R$ together with the existence of a suitable $t$-structure should imply that $\tilde R$ is an equivalence, but I cannot find an applicable reference at the moment.

Comment: The functor $\tilde{R}$ has been also constructed 
by Pridham in https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0637.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Could you help me understand, or point to a reference, what does "geometric" mean for a motive. I familiar with the general construction of taking nisnevich sheaves and localizing by $A^1$-equivalences and stabilizing then rationalizing. What do I need to do from this point to get "geometric motives? Persumably those should correspond to the numerical equivalence relation, how is it encoded in this language?

Comment: @SaalHardali Geometric motives are the compact objects in the ∞-category of motives.